# How do i refresh csv data set in quicksight and not replace the data set as this loses my calcs

Tags: csv, upload, dashboard, datastore, amazon-quicksight

I am looking to refresh a data set in quicksight, this is in Spice. The data set comes from a csv file that has been updated and now has more data than the original file I uploaded.

I can't seem to find a way to simply repoint to the same file with same format. I know how to replace the file but whenever i do this it states that it can't create some of my calculated fields and so drops multiple rows of data!

I assume I'm missing something obvious but I can't seem to find the right method or any help on the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, QuickSight doesn't support refreshing file data-sets to my knowledge. One solution, however, is to put your CSV in S3 and refresh from there.

The one gotcha with this approach is that you'll need to create a manifest file pointing to your CSV. This isn't too difficult and the [QuickSight documentation is pretty helpful](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/create-a-data-set-s3.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when this was introduced but you can now do this exact thing through the "Edit Dataset", starting either from the Dataset page or from the 'pencil' -> Edit dataset inside an Analysis. It is called "update file" and will result in an updated dataset (additional or different data) without losing anything from your analysis including calculated fields, filters etc.

The normal caveat applies in that the newer uploaded file MUST contain the same column names and datatypes as the original - although it can also contain additional columns if needed.

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You can replace the datasource by going into the **Analysis** and clicking on the pencil icon as highlighted in Step 1. By replacing dataset, you will not lose any new calculated fields that might have been calculated already on the old dataset.

[image]

If you try to replace the data source by going into the **Datasets** as highlighted below, you'll lose all calculated fields and modifications etc

[image]